# JAVA Spring boot how to post arraylist in Postman

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest

I am trying to save some books via request but I am getting errors. How do I exactly do this? This is the model

```
@Entity
public class Reservation {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
private String user;
private int period;
@OneToMany
private List<Books> books;

public static String error () {
    return "Input error";
}
public String getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public int getPeriod() { return period;}
public void setPeriod(int period) {this.period = period;}
public List<Books> getBooks() { return books;}
public int getId() {return id;}
public void setId(int id) {this.id = id;}

@Entity
public class Books implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
    private int id;
    private  String  name;
}
}
```

Controller:

```
  @PostMapping("/reserveBook")
  public String reserveBook(@RequestBody Reservation reservation)
{

    if (reservation.getPeriod() > 2)
        return Book.error();


    else{

        reserveRepo.save(reservation);
        return "success";
    }
   }
```

Tried json like this
{
"user": "Jason",
"books":[{"name":  "Wonders"}, {"name": "Good classics"}],
"period": 2
}

Comment: When you passed in that json, what did you get?

Comment: "I am trying to save some books via request but I am getting errors"
Could you please include errors in the question.

Comment: "Invalid JSON input: Cannot construct instance of `com.example.demo.model.Reservation$Books` (although at least one Creator exists): non-static inner classes like this can only by instantiated using default, no-argument constructor; nested excecptio..........

Answer (score 0):

What exact error you are getting? Can you try to make your inner class static? Like

public static class Books implements Serializable